# Reverse Proxy (mod_rewrite) and Rails (absolute paths)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, ruby-on-rails

I have front end rails app, that reverse proxies to any of a number of backend rails apps depending on URL, for example

`http://www.my_host.com/app_one` reverse proxies to `http://www.remote_host_running_app_one.com`

such that a URL like `http://www.my_host.com/app_one/users` will display the contents of `http://www.remote_host_running_app_one.com/users`

I have a large, and ever expanding number of backends, so they can not be explicitly listed anywhere other than a database.  This is no problem for mod_rewrite using a prg:/ rewrite map reverse proxy.

The question is, the urls returned by rails helpers have the form `/controller/action` making them absolute to the root.  This is a problem for the page served by mod_rewrite because links on the proxied page appear as absolute to the domain. i.e.:

`http://www.my_host.com/app_one/controller/action` has links that end up looking like `/controller/action/`  when they need to look like `/app_one/controller/action`

mod_proxy_html seems like the right idea, but it doesn't seem to be as dynamic as I would need, since the rules need to be hard coded into the config files.

Is there a way to fix this server-side, so that the links will be routed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.

```
ProxyPass /app_one http://www.remote_host_runing_app_one.com
ProxyPassReverse /app_one http://www.remote_host_running_app_one.com
```

Though you are better off running your ruby apps under their named directories and reverse proxying directly back instead of doing a rewrite to change the uri.

You can look at unicorn, passenger or thin to run the ruby apps under to give more flexibility with how they are run.